# Seemingly unrelated use of std::thread causing later OpenGL commands to run slowly

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, concurrency

I'm writing an application in C++ using OpenGL with GLFW, and GLEW for graphics. Each frame, the program completes some computations which are quite expensive time-wise, before displaying the calculated data to the screen in a visual manner. In order to speed up the prior calculations I used multithreading with std::thread to offload the work, before joining all the threads and collecting the data in a single vertex buffer, and drawing it to the screen.

However, after doing this I found that the rendering became very jittery and laggy. I've managed to reproduce this effect in a minimal example:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

void DoNothing()
{
    // I do nothing
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    glewInit();
    
    glfwSwapInterval(0); // Disable VSync

    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left  
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right 
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top   
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // ===== Initialize Some Threads to do Nothing =====
        int nthreads = 1;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(nthreads);
        for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < nthreads; threadIndex++)
            threads.emplace_back(DoNothing);
        for (std::thread& t : threads)
            t.join();
        // =================================================

        glFinish(); // Ensure OpenGL is totally finished before starting the timer

        auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glFinish(); // Make sure all commands are finished before stopping timer
        auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto startMicro = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(startTime).time_since_epoch().count();
        auto endMicro = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime).time_since_epoch().count();

        long long int duration = endMicro - startMicro;
        std::cout << "Took: " << duration * 0.001 << "ms\n";
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

This code is copied almost directly from the minimal sample on learnopengl.com. The only significant change is to the main render loop:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // ===== Initialize Some Threads to do Nothing =====
        int nthreads = 1;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(nthreads);
        for (int threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < nthreads; threadIndex++)
            threads.emplace_back(DoNothing);
        for (std::thread& t : threads)
            t.join();
        // =================================================

        glFinish(); // Ensure OpenGL is totally finished before starting the timer

        auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glFinish(); // Make sure all commands are finished before stopping timer
        auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto startMicro = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(startTime).time_since_epoch().count();
        auto endMicro = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(endTime).time_since_epoch().count();

        long long int duration = endMicro - startMicro;
        std::cout << "Took: " << duration * 0.001 << "ms\n";
    }
```

Where I initialize a single thread (since the variable 'nThreads' is set to 1) to 'DoNothing()' before joining it and continuing. However, the timings suffered a drastic change.

The timings with nThreads set to 0 (threading disabled) are as follows:

> Took: 5.14ms
> Took: 1.011ms
> Took: 0.615ms
> Took: 0.883ms
> Took: 0.894ms
> Took: 0.847ms
> Took: 0.831ms
> Took: 0.477ms
> Took: 0.456ms
> Took: 0.874ms
> Took: 0.451ms
> Took: 0.46ms
> Took: 0.488ms
> Took: 1.323ms
> Took: 0.932ms
> Took: 0.887ms
> Took: 0.611ms
> Took: 0.623ms
> Took: 0.576ms
> Took: 2.17ms
> Took: 0.453ms
> Took: 0.348ms
> Took: 0.41ms
> Took: 0.566ms
> Took: 0.427ms
> Took: 0.366ms
> Took: 0.406ms
> Took: 1.143ms
> Took: 0.584ms
> Took: 1.192ms
> Took: 1.586ms
> Took: 0.945ms
> Took: 1.482ms
> Took: 0.69ms
> Took: 0.588ms
> Took: 0.856ms
> Took: 0.592ms
> Took: 0.533ms
> Took: 0.938ms
> Took: 0.71ms
> Took: 0.592ms
> Took: 0.54ms
> Took: 0.553ms
> Took: 0.521ms
> Took: 0.549ms

Whereas the timings with nThreads set to 1 were:

> Took: 63.177ms
> Took: 0.983ms
> Took: 0.841ms
> Took: 1.004ms
> Took: 0.336ms
> Took: 92.499ms
> Took: 98.086ms
> Took: 93.81ms
> Took: 93.909ms
> Took: 106.853ms
> Took: 96.406ms
> Took: 102.337ms
> Took: 109.134ms
> Took: 104.278ms
> Took: 101.201ms
> Took: 102.328ms
> Took: 94.609ms
> Took: 92.916ms
> Took: 62.069ms
> Took: 98.112ms
> Took: 108.483ms
> Took: 101.531ms
> Took: 100.358ms
> Took: 100.211ms
> Took: 93.724ms
> Took: 99.032ms
> Took: 92.898ms
> Took: 97.362ms
> Took: 95.587ms
> Took: 93.366ms
> Took: 60.48ms
> Took: 0.438ms
> Took: 0.314ms
> Took: 0.296ms
> Took: 0.291ms
> Took: 0.289ms
> Took: 0.36ms
> Took: 0.327ms
> Took: 0.315ms
> Took: 0.293ms
> Took: 0.286ms
> Took: 0.546ms
> Took: 0.291ms
> Took: 0.289ms
> Took: 0.303ms
> Took: 0.295ms
> Took: 0.298ms
> Took: 0.301ms
> Took: 102.664ms
> Took: 97.894ms
> Took: 99.621ms
> Took: 60.743ms
> Took: 0.484ms
> Took: 0.348ms
> Took: 0.302ms
> Took: 0.295ms
> Took: 0.304ms
> Took: 0.558ms
> Took: 0.297ms
> Took: 0.306ms
> Took: 0.293ms
> Took: 0.291ms
> Took: 0.339ms
> Took: 0.301ms
> Took: 0.304ms
> Took: 0.379ms
> Took: 0.399ms
> Took: 0.3ms
> Took: 0.299ms
> Took: 0.295ms
> Took: 0.291ms
> Took: 0.322ms
> Took: 0.775ms
> Took: 0.307ms
> Took: 0.295ms
> Took: 0.294ms
> Took: 0.286ms
> Took: 0.308ms
> Took: 0.342ms
> Took: 0.454ms
> Took: 0.314ms

For some reason, initializing a single thread that runs no code is causing these times to be sporadic, sometimes they are just fine and yet sometimes they are ridiculously high. In my original application these large times are only exaggerated, and are causing a significant issue.

I appreciate any help people can offer me.

Code samples are compiled using MSVC2022, and run on an NVIDIA 1060 and an AMD Ryzen 5 1600X.

Comment: Spawning and joining/deleting threads can be quite an expensive and non-deterministic process, since it involves interacting with the OS's scheduler, setting up and tearing down per-thread resources, and so on.  You should definitely change it to use a thread pool instead; that way the threads are launched just once at startup and stick around the entire time, and you hand them tasks as necessary for them to do.  With the thread pool you avoid the thread-startup and thread-shutdown overhead during your program's execution.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You were right, I implemented a very simple thread pool in my code and the performance issues are gone. I had no idea initializing new threads was so slow.